# react-i18next: When the key exists in en.json I get this error -> i18next::translator: missingKey en translation

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I am getting a lot of these errors:

```
i18next::translator: missingKey en translation
```

screenshot from my console:
[image: Errors in console]

This is one of the objects in `/locales/en.json` that shows those keys are not missing.

```
  "template-manager": {
    "desktop-button": "Desktop",
    "header": "Custom Order Forms",
    "header-button": "New Order Form Template",
    "mobile-button": "Mobile",
    "preview-button": "Preview",
    "redo-button": "Redo",
    "tablet-button": "Tablet",
    "toggle-device-Frame": "Toggle Device Frame",
    "undo-button": "Undo"
  }
```

This error isn't happening on all of the keys, just some of them.

We are using a script that adds all of the keys for us where the text for i18n is wrapped in a `<trans>` tag:

```
"updateLanguageKeys": "rm -rf public/locales/en.json && npx babel -f .babelrc 'src/**/*.{js,jsx}'",
```

contents of .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        [
            "@babel/preset-react",
            {
                "runtime": "automatic"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "i18next-extract",
            {
                "discardOldKeys": true,
                "outputPath": "public/locales/{{locale}}.json"
            }
        ],
        ["@babel/proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
        ["@babel/proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
        ["@babel/proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }],
        ["@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread", { "loose": true }]
    ]
}
```

Here are the settings:

```
i18n.use(detector)
    .use(backend)
    .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
    .init({
        returnEmptyString: false,
        backend: { loadPath: process.env.LOCALES_PATH },
        whitelist: ['en', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'pt'],
        fallbackLng: 'en', // use en if detected lng is not available
        debug: true, // Use this to see what's going on in console
        react: {
            useSuspense: false
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
        }
    })
```

Comment: is it happening on key's with a - in the key? like `redo-button`

Comment: In my project I am using camel cases instead of Dashes like `redoButton`.

Comment: @SanishJoseph that is a good thought.  I tried changing to camel case and still have the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the environment variable in this.

Environment variables in a React app have to be prepended with `REACT_APP` so It needed to be changed to `process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALES_PATH`

```
i18n.use(detector)
    .use(backend)
    .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
    .init({
        returnEmptyString: false,
        backend: { loadPath: process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALES_PATH }, // <--right there
        whitelist: ['en', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'pt'],
        fallbackLng: 'en', // use en if detected lng is not available
        debug: true, // Use this to see what's going on in console
        react: {
            useSuspense: false
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
        }
    })
```